# Can google datastore manage lots of continous write operations?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using google app engine to read data from a google cloud sql database and write some of its data and some derived data in google datastore, the database right now doesn't have lots of entries per day, but it's estimated to have around 200-300 entries per day on the future. I'm testing to write all the data from the whole databse that now has a number aproximately equal to these entries in it doesn't work properly, first of all not all entries are being taken and derived data is sometimes properly written and other times not, the result changes everytime I do a reading from the database, so I guess that at least partially google datastore has something that is related to the problem.

Don't know if google datastore could fall into race conditions or something like that, although it would be sort of strange, but I'd like to know if someone has had problems similar to mine and if how he was able to solve it if he could.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Are you getting any errors when writing? 2. How do you check that data was properly written? With a query?

Comment: OTOH, GAE datastore can verifiably write millions of entities a day.

Comment: 3. Do you write new entities or do you overwrite existing ones (= same key)? If overwriting, do you write 200-300 entities in one request ora  t short write intervals?

Comment: Don't get any error, just some of the latest entries seem not to be written for unknown reasons. I check it in datastore viewer from appengine.google.com. I'm doing both things, insert new things and at the same time I check some things while reading that cause me to update things already written, I've realized that if it fails it is only when there 2 consecutive entries that have the same value in a certain field (wich is not the key field), but sometimes it also works even they are consecutive. I write them at once.

Comment: Does this change over time, i.e. if you reload datastore viewer after couple of minutes, do you see updated entities?

Comment: No, it stays the same.

Comment: You should confirm this by getting the entity by key and not a query.

Comment: My experience suggests there are no failed writes without an error of some form.